# RNCEP R package causing new R session, not working

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I'm working in R using the `RNCEP` package to download reanalysis data.

If I run

```
install.packages("RNCEP", dependencies=TRUE)
library(RNCEP)
```

I get a behavior that I've never seen before in any package: an XQuartz window opens up. If I try to run any of the example scripts, I get an error message that looks like

> Error in NCEP.gather.pressure(variable = variable, months.minmax = months.minmax,  :There is a problem connecting to the NCEP database with the information provided.

If I close the XQuartz window, my RStudio session crashes.

I've tried removing and reinstalling multiple times, but I get same results every time. According to [the developer's web site](https://sites.google.com/site/michaelukemp/rncep),

> For Unix-alike (e.g. Mac and Linux) users running R 2.8.0 or greater, loading of the RNCEP package may fail if Tcl/Tk version >= 8.4 is not installed (see section A.2.1 of R Installation and Administration).  For Mac OS X users, Tcl/Tk may be obtained here.

I'm running OSX El Capitan, so that may have something to do with my problem. I ran `brew cask install tcl` to get tcl through homebrew, but that hasn't had an impact.

FWIW: my R version information

```
>version
               _                                          
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0                  
arch           x86_64                                     
os             darwin15.3.0                               
system         x86_64, darwin15.3.0                       
status         Revised                                    
major          3                                          
minor          2.4                                        
year           2016                                       
month          03                                         
day            16                                         
svn rev        70336                                      
language       R                                          
version.string R version 3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336)
nickname       Very Secure Dishes
```

An update: I've tried running R both through homebrew:

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
brew install R --with-openblas
brew install Caskroom/cask/rstudio
```

and by fully removing those options and installing from the web site (I've heard of people having trouble with homebrew R and Rstudio). Same results.

However, the `RNCEP` packages works if I'm running R in terminal for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to [Kevin Ushey](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/210610927-RStudio-crashes-with-RNCEP-package-tcl-tk-issue-most-likely-?page=1#community_comment_214166997) for noting that the issue was not with tcl/tk but with the RStudio download mechanism. He recommended setting

```
options(download.file.method = "internal")
```

which did the trick.